# URL товара и категории с одинаковым префиксом Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть код, который в Woocommerce меняет базу в url категорий на базу url магазина. То есть если у нас база url магазина `products`, то нужно в настройках Постоянных ссылок выставить Базу категорий товара тоже `products` а для постоянных ссылок товара выбрать такое `/products/%product_cat%/`. Потом вставляем нижеследующий код в functions.php и все работает.

```
/**
 * Set product category base url same as a shop base
 *
 * @param array $rules
 *
 * @see https://gist.github.com/levantoan/fc705c5ae4739e6d87e2ec51b257ea5c
 * @return array
 */
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array',
    function( $rules ) {
        $new_rules = array();
        global $sitepress;
        if ( $sitepress ) {
            // Disable wpml filters to get all the product terms.
            remove_filter( 'get_terms_args', array( $sitepress, 'get_terms_args_filter' ) );
            remove_filter( 'get_term', array( $sitepress, 'get_term_adjust_id' ) );
            remove_filter( 'terms_clauses', array( $sitepress, 'terms_clauses' ) );
            // Get the terms.
            $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'post_type' => 'product', 'hide_empty' => false ) );
        } else {
            $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'post_type' => 'product', 'hide_empty' => false ) );
        }
        // Check if any terms are present and the there are no errors.
        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                // Detect term language.
                $language_code = apply_filters( 'wpml_element_language_code', null, array( 'element_id' => (int) $term->term_taxonomy_id, 'element_type' => 'product_cat' ) );

                // Check the language code.
                if ( $language_code === 'en' ) {
                    $siteurl = esc_url( home_url( '/en/' ) );
                } else {
                    $siteurl = esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );
                }
                $term_slug = $term->slug;
                $baseterm = str_replace( $siteurl, '', get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' ) );

                // Rules for a specific category.
                $new_rules[ $baseterm . '?$' ] = 'index.php?product_cat=' . $term_slug;
                // Rules for a category pagination.
                $new_rules[ $baseterm . '/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$' ] = 'index.php?product_cat=' . $term_slug . '&paged=$matches[1]';
                $new_rules[ $baseterm . '(?:feed/)?(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' ] = 'index.php?product_cat=' . $term_slug . '&feed=$matches[1]';
            }
        }
        if ( $sitepress ) {
            add_filter( 'terms_clauses', array( $sitepress, 'terms_clauses' ), 10, 4 );
            add_filter( 'get_term', array( $sitepress, 'get_term_adjust_id' ), 1, 1 );
            add_filter( 'get_terms_args', array( $sitepress, 'get_terms_args_filter' ), 10, 2 );
        }
        return $new_rules + $rules;
    }
);

/**
 * Flush rewrite rules when create new term
 * need for a new product category rewrite rules
 *
 */
function imp_create_term() {
    flush_rewrite_rules( false );
}
add_action( 'create_term', 'imp_create_term' );
```

Код работает нормально. Но Мне нужно поменять изменить структуру url для товара, исключив в нем категорию. То есть сейчас url товара выглядит так - `site.com/products/category-name/product-name`, а нужно чтобы было `site.com/products/product-name`. Понятно, что нужно изменить постоянную ссылку на товар в настройках Постоянных ссылок, но тогда на месте страницы товара появляется ошибка 404. Подскажите как изменить этот код, чтобы все работало нормально???

Comment: https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/woocommerce-kill-performance/

Comment: А все таки? Там старый сайт, заказчики как-то переносят его, хотят сохранить SEO, и на старом сайте все это работает у них

Comment: Всё-таки не нужно искать приключений на седалище. А "вопрос с СЕО" легко решается 301м и родным каноникалом. А в статье всё написано.